# Scalamock: Mocking a generic case class results in type mismatch

Tags: mongodb, scala, unit-testing, scalamock

I'm using Mongodb as persistence in my application and I'm currently writing test for my code. My CUT looks as following

```
implicit def storageHandler[M[_]: Monad](
    implicit mongoDatabase: MongoDatabase
) = new Storage.Handler[M] {
    override def store(order: Order): M[Unit] = Monad[M].pure {
      val collection: MongoCollection[Document] = mongoDatabase.getCollection("order")

      val document: Document = Document(order.asJson.toString)

      collection.insertOne(document).subscribe((x: Completed) => ())
   }
}
```

My mock is getting properly injected by using implicits. I'm mocking the getCollection call which on it's own should result in another mock, this time of type

```
MongoCollection[org.mongodb.scala.bson.collection.immutable.Document]
```

So what I'm doing is the following

```
val mongoCollection: MongoCollection[Document] = mock[MongoCollection[Document]]

(mongoDatabase.getCollection[Document] _).expects("order").once().returning(mongoCollection)
```

But this result in the following error

```
type mismatch;
[error]  found   : com.mongodb.async.client.MongoCollection[TResult]
[error]  required: com.mongodb.async.client.MongoCollection[org.mongodb.scala.bson.collection.immutable.Document]
[error]  val mongoCollection: MongoCollection[Document] = mock[MongoCollection[Document]]
```

TResult is the generic parameter from the mongoCollection, which looks like this:

```
case class MongoCollection[TResult](private val wrapped: JMongoCollection[TResult]) { 
.... 
}
```

It seems that the generic parameter is not properly "adjusted" (I'm not sure how to call it) to Document

Comment: Hi, looks like you came across this bug: https://github.com/paulbutcher/ScalaMock/issues/170 . It's being worked on, but difficult to fix

Comment: @PhilippM Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1):

Specifying the type parameter upfront should work, or, if your interface is fully abstract, you can use a Proxy mock for that:

```
import org.scalamock.scalatest.MixedMockFactory
import org.scalatest.{FlatSpec, Matchers}

import scala.reflect.ClassTag

class Issue170Test extends FlatSpec with Matchers with MixedMockFactory {
  behavior of "ScalaMock"

  it should "mock this" in {
    class Foo[T: ClassTag]
    "val m = mock[Foo[Nothing]]" should compile // this one fails :(
  }

  trait TotallyAbstract[T] {
    def foo: Int
    def bar: T
  }

  it should "work with this workaround" in {
    class Foo[T: ClassTag]
    abstract class Foo2 extends Foo[Int] // workaround: specify type parameter
    "val m = mock[Foo2]" should compile
    "val m2 = Proxy.mock[TotallyAbstract[Int]]" should compile
  }
}
```